# Business Validation Error: Unexpected Internal Error. (-30003) - QuickBooks Java SDK

Tags: java, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

i cannot create invoice in QuickBooks online using Java SDK v2.9.1

- company location: India

  currency: INR

due to some validation error not very clearly returned in API fault response.

i believe the payload is complete as the same works with US sandbox environment.

any insight into this?

thanks in advance :)

Request:

```
{
  "ApplyTaxAfterDiscount": false,
  "AutoDocNumber": false,
  "CurrencyRef": {
      "value": "INR"
  },
  "DepartmentRef": {
      "value": "1"
  },
  "DocNumber": "00006",
  "DueDate": "2017-06-13",
  "Line": [
      {
          "Amount": 110.0,
          "Description": "00006",
          "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
          "SalesItemLineDetail": {
              "ItemRef": {
                  "value": "25"
              },
              "Qty": 1,
              "TaxCodeRef": {
                  "value": "3"
              },
              "UnitPrice": 110.0
          }
      }
  ],
  "ShipAddr": {
      "City": "HD",
      "CountryCode": "IND",
      "Line1": "55-DP-1",
      "Line2": "",
      "PostalCode": "600660"
  },
  "ShipDate": "2017-06-13",
  "TotalAmt": 110.0,
  "TxnDate": "2017-06-13"
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "Fault": {
      "Error": [
          {
              "Detail": "Business Validation Error: Unexpected Internal Error. (-30003)",
              "Message": "A business validation error has occurred while processing your request",
              "code": "6000",
              "element": ""
          }
      ],
      "type": "ValidationFault"
  },
  "time": "2017-06-13T05:52:29.153-07:00"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

while sending this request please check in your java code for correct date formats, 
I got same error code when I trying to post QBO bill API with txnDate, but unfortunately it in my code format of date changed and I got above error. After converting date into correct format "yyyy-MM-DD", QBO bill payment API works fine for me.
So first check in your code or print json request data to check date format.